# Rails form for a single has_many association: make it impossible to edit all instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a blog app. My `Post` model `has_many :revisions` (one revision for each edit you make).

My `Post` model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :revisions`

What's the best way to prevent the user from editing ALL the `revisions` of some `post` (which they can do by hacking the form)?

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
    = f.error_notification

    = f.simple_fields_for :revisions, @revision do |r|
        = r.input :title
        = r.input :body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an option to accepts_nested_attributes_for called :reject_if, like this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :revisions, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
```

Within the proc passed in the option, you can specify additional criteria on which revisions are eligible to be edited.

Comment: The solution: `reject_if: proc{|attrs| attrs["id"].present? }` The `id` is included with instances that exist, and isnt included in the new instance.